# contraction mapping and convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am having difficulties arranging and concluding the proof...

Suppose $f$ maps the open interval $E$ into itself, $0 < b < 1$, $f$ has property $X(b)$ (that property is Lipschitz continuous), and
$x_0 \in E$ Prove that the sequence $\{ x_k\}$ defined recursively by $x_k = f(x_{k−1})$ for $k \geq 1$
converges.

what I started with:

Given: $x_0 \in E$ $f(x_{k-1}) = x_k$ $0 < b <1$, $f$ has the property $X(b) \in E$, $|f'(x)| \leq b$, $x_0 \in E$

from $|f'(x)| \leq b$

$f(x_0) - f(x) \leq y+x_1$ becomes $f(x_0) = x_1$

$x_k = f(x_{k-1})$. for $ K\geq 1$

I am stuck and not sure if whatI am starting with is the right track :(

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about what you mean by $y$

I think you should notice that Lipchitz condition doesn't mean the existence of derivative, so you are not allowed to use $f'(x)$

Here's my proof

By the condition, given $x_0\in E$, we have $x_n\in E,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

By Lipschitz condition, we have

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq b|x-y|,\forall x,y\in E$$

specially,

$$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|=|f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)|\leq b|x_{n+1}-x_n|,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$

let $n=0,1,...,k-1$, and multiply the inequalities together, we have

$$|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|\leq b^k|x_1-x_0|$$

note that given $x_0$, $x_1-x_0$ is a constant, so when $m>n$

$$|x_m-x_n|\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}b^k|x_1-x_0|\leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty b^k|x_1-x_0|=\frac{b^n}{1-b}|x_1-x_0|$$

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N,\frac{b^N}{1-b}|x_1-x_0|<\epsilon$, then we have $|x_m-x_n|<\epsilon,\forall m>n>N$

by Cauchy's criterion, it is equivalent to the convergence of $\lbrace x_n\rbrace$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It has helped me a great deal. I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but how is it that we get $$\lim_{k\to\infty}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|=0$$ and not $$\lim_{k\to\infty}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}| \leq 0$$?

Or rather how did you conclude that? thanks

Comment: note that $0\leq |x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq b^k|x_1-x_0|$, and $0$ and $b^k|x_1-x_0|$ has the same limit $0$, so we conclude that $|x_{k+1}-x_k|\to 0,k\to \infty$

Comment: Is that sufficient to prove that it is Cauchy? shouldn't there be an $\epsilon>0$ for all values greater than N?

Comment: You are correct, I made a mistake